# How can I configure Gmail mobile version to use the old version?

Tags: gmail, mobile

The new Gmail mobile design is a bit heavy for my mobile telephone. How can I configure it to use the old design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to choose the older version when you scroll to the bottom of the page. Select that option and you will be directed to use the older version of Gmail.

[image: Options at the bottom of the page]